# how to rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique error in controller and re-render form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, exception

My controller's #create action fails because of uniqueness constraint I've added to to the name and title attribute of my `Boo` model.

```
def create
 @boo = current_user.my_boos.create(boo_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @boo.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thanks!" }
    format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @boo }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @boo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Submitting with this action gives a Railsy looking `PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_boos_on_name_and_title"`error, which I think would be better displayed as an error message and a re-rendered page.

Everything I'm reading says that rescuing from Exception is bad, while rescuing from StandardError is good. But I've yet to find anything that explains how to display that error more nicely for the end user without rescuing from Exception. Like, it doesn't seem that `StandardError` works with the db.

Comment: What is the point of doing `@boo.save` after you've already done `@boo.create`?

Comment: @jvillian aren't i doing an `if @boo.save`? in which case, the idea is: create the record, and if it saves redirect to root_path, otherwise re-render page.

Comment: If `@boo.create` is successful, then `if @boo.save` will always be true. I think you want `@boo.new` instead.

Comment: @jvillian late reply: i'm confused by what you're saying. that's precisely what i'm doing. if `@boo.create` is successful, then i want to redirect to x and render y, otherwise i want to do something else.

Comment: Look at how matthewd did it. That is the correct way. matthewd first uses `new` (second line), then test `if @boo.save` (fifth line). You use `create`, then test `if @boo.save`. `create` then `save` (your way) is *not* precisely the same as `new` then `save` (the correct way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer is to rescue the specific exception you want to recover from, and then handle it as you see fit... something like:

```
def create
  @boo = current_user.my_boos.new(boo_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    begin
      if @boo.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thanks!" }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @boo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @boo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    rescue PG::UniqueViolation
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: ["We've already got one"], status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

(rescuing StandardError there should work just as well, but while safe, it's much broader than we need.)

**However**, I'd suggest that a more "Railsy" solution is to define a uniqueness validation in your model, in addition to the DB constraint, so it'll be handled by the existing `if @boo.save` conditional.

Answer (score 3):

You can add validation to your Boo model, it'll prevent from trying to save non-valid record and there will be no need to rescue from PG::UniqueViolation error:

```
class Boo < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :title }
  # ...
end
```

(c) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: Unless you have multiple web processes and want to ensure data integrity. Then it's recommended to also add the validation to your DB. 

See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations